# What happens when a Demon tries to Read an Angel's Mind?

Tags: demon-the-descent

What happens if a Demon tries the Mind Reading form ability on an angel?  The rules from the DtD manual state:

> System: The demon only has to see her intended target; the target does not have to see the demon or know she is there. As a reflexive action, the player rolls her Wits + Persuasion + Primum vs. Resolve + Primum. If successful, the demon can read the surface thoughts of the victim for as long as she maintains concentration.

It's odd that the manual assumes that the Demon is trying to read the mind of another Demon (hence the "vs. Resolve + Primum"). Angel's don't have Resolve, so maybe Resistance+Rank?

If it's successful, does the Demon know that the target is an Angel? Does the Angel have any way to detect the use of an ability on them? Otherwise, this seems like a perfect Angel-detector.

Answer (score 3):

Resistance + Rank

You’re right about the roll for the Angel to make. Angels replace Resolve with Resistance (p341). As for The Primum, the term you are looking for is Supernatural Tolerance. Each book lists rolls like this using the Supernatural Tolerance trait for PCs in that book. In this case it is Primum for Demons. But Rank is the Supernatural Tolerance trait for Angels and in the sidebar of page 340, you will see:
“They all have slightly different rules, described in the appropriate rulebooks, but all share one quality; they are added to Resistance Attributes when levying Resistance based penalties to the dice pools of many supernatural powers. The various supernatural traits, including Rank, are interchangeable for this purpose” Thus we add the Angel’s Rank for resisting the power.

As for what thoughts an Angel would have, that is harder to say. On page 336, the description of Angels and other ephemeral beings states “their thoughts are alien to humans.” And that would certainly be true for some Angels all of the time. But I would think that, depending on the cover, some Angels would have thoughts programmed to protect their covers. So your mileage may vary.

Ghostdriver suggested in the comments that as a Demon, you may be able to make some sense of “alien” Angel thoughts with a separate Wits + Computer roll. This would be similar thematically to that same roll used within the Download Knowledge Embed (p133).

Comment: On the "alien to humans" part, you could make it interesting. After all, Demons are not human either. But you could have them make a roll to decipher what they are thinking. Something like Wits+Computer or something since it may be partially code?

Comment: My initial thought when I read your comment is that an angel is like a computer in the same way a ps4 is like an abacus. So I doubted using Wits + Computer and had been thinking Wits + Occult. However I did some more reading and saw Wits + Computer used for the Download Knowledge Embed and that seems like a good fit. Thank you. I will update my answer.